# Rails ActiveStorage rails_blob_path generating invalid url with missing /rails in start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, rails-activestorage

I am on:
Rails: `6.0.1`
Ruby: `2.6.5`

And I am using **`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path`** helper in one of my serializers to generate path to a pdf file. And it has been working great in development. Generating url like: 
`/rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename` 

as expected.

But in production, same helper produces wrong url in the format of:
 `/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename`
**notice the missing `/rails` part in start.**

This obviously causes no route matches errors when the url is accessed.

I have been trying to dig and find cuase, temporarily i have added following to my `routes.rb`

```
get '/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename', to: 'active_storage/blobs#show'
```

I know this is just a hack, but it works for now. I am looking for the real reason and fix through this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i was doing some hit and trial and I noticed this was happening in my production console:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(Record.last.file)
=> "https://mywebsite.com//rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--8994a079b16e683a18ef1be83a6ae7f5c3/filename.pdf"
```

Notice the `//rails` part, it is invalid as it has double forward slashes. This lead me to the solution.

## Solution

I had this in my `config/environment.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

and default url options in `production.rb` looked like:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['SERVER_URL'] }
```

`SERVER_BASE_URL` was the culprit, it was set to: `https://mywebsite.com/` when i changed this to `https://mywebsite.com` and restarted my server. Boom!

Although it is not very clear to me WHY is this behavior as such and if this is a bug. But this is what worked for me after hours of struggle.